# Проблемы с QSvgRenderer

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, svg, pyqt5

## Делаю векторную рисовалку.

Суть алгоритма:

[image: Суть алгоритма:]

Алгоритм:

- Когда пользователь рисует, его каракули записываются в SVG-файл с помощью библиотеки SvgWriter.
- После этого QSvgRenderer должен вытащить данные из файла и отобразить все это на QImage, который будет нарисован на QPainter в paintEvent.

Проблема в то, что QSvgRenderer обрабатывает файл только при  запуске программы, т.е. во время рисования на QPainter ничего не рисуется.

Вот исходный код:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPainterPath, QColor, QPen, QImage, QIcon
from PyQt5.QtSvg import QSvgWidget, QSvgRenderer
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize
import svgwrite


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.last_x = 0 #last point x pos
        self.last_y = 0#last point y pos
        self.itr = 0 #iteration of points
        self.itr_step = 5

        self.pen = QPen(QColor(10,10,16), 2, cap=32)

        self.init_UI()

    def init_UI(self):
        self.rend = QSvgRenderer('drawing.svg')

        self.dwg = svgwrite.Drawing('drawing.svg', size=('600px', '600px'))
        self.dwg.add(self.dwg.line((0, 0), (10, 0), stroke=svgwrite.rgb(10, 10, 16, '%'), stroke_linecap="round"))
        self.dwg.save()

        self.cnv = QImage(2560, 1440, QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied)

        self.setGeometry(729, 410, 600, 600) #TODO change size and start pos before relize
        self.setWindowTitle('SmartWrite')

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)

        #qp.drawImage(0, 0, self.cnv)
        #self.dwg.save()
        self.rend.render(qp)
        qp.end()

    def draw(self, x, y):
        painter = QPainter()
        painter.begin(self.cnv)

        painter.setPen(self.pen)
        painter.drawLine(self.last_x,self.last_y, x, y)
        self.dwg.add(self.dwg.line((self.last_x,self.last_y), (x, y), 
                                   stroke=svgwrite.rgb(10, 10, 16, '%'), stroke_linecap='round',
                                   stroke_width=5))
        self.dwg.save()
        print(x, y)

        painter.end()
        self.update()
        self.last_x = x
        self.last_y = y

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.last_x = event.x()
        self.last_y = event.y()

        self.draw(event.x(), event.y())

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.itr += 1

        if not self.itr % self.itr_step:
            self.draw(event.x(), event.y())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = Window()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: `svgwrite` является костылем, т.к. рисовать svg можно через [QSvgGenerator](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qsvggenerator.html). Он тоже умеет через QPainter :)